# Replacing classpath argument with CLASSPATH environment variable

Tags: classpath, java

### Requirements:

- Command-line only, i.e. no IDE's
- Do not want to use `classpath` argument
- OS: OS X v10.6.8

### Steps:

- Setup CLASSPATH environment variable: `export CLASSPATH="/path-jar-files-are-at/*"`
- Compile my java app: `javac MyApp.java`
- Launch my java app: `java MyApp`

### After launching, the following error appears:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MyApp
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MyApp
```

### Using classpath argument doesn't have this problem

- Compile my java app: `javac -classpath /path-jar-files-are-at/* MyApp.java`
- Launch my java app: `java -classpath /path-jar-files-are-at/* MyApp`

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the path (location) of MyApp.java and MyApp.class?

Comment: `java MyApp.java` shouldn't work.  It should be `java MyApp`. Typo?

Comment: Thanks @JimGarrison, made relevant updates

Comment: @AVD: path of MyApp files are nestled in my ~/Desktop directory and the path of the jar files I am linking to are nestled in my /Applications directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CLASSPATH should not contain the trailing "/*" - that is not going to give you a valid classpath.  The shell is expanding the /* and separating the list with whitespace/newlines - rather than the ":" character.

If you still really want it to work this (dynamic) way, try something like this:

```
export CP=`ls /path-jar-files-are-at/*`; CP=`echo $CP | sed 's/\.jar\s/.jar:/g'`; CP="$CP:/path-jar-files-are-at"
```

Comment: Did you mean "trailing asterisk"?  The JVM (not the shell) interprets that as meaning "all .jar files in the directory".  Also, the asterisk is not expanded when setting the value of the environment variable.

Comment: Yes, corrected - I didn't notice I had to escape the asterisk.

Comment: This answer is still incorrect.  The trailing `/*` if set in the environment variable where it is read directly by the JVM and not interpreted by the shell, is interpreted as meaning "all jar files in the named directory".

Comment: @Jim.  If I run the line of code I posted in a linux shell, CP is set to the expanded list of jars plus the folder.  This looks to be one way to solve the requirement.